# Проблема с установкой Ubuntu на флешку

Tags: ubuntu, установка, загрузчик

Я устанавливаю Ubuntu на флешку, поделив её на 4 сектора (efi на 500мб, ext4 / на 30720мб, ext4 /home тоже на 30720мб и остальное оставляю пустым, чтобы потом использовать как флешку). Все разделы добавлял в начало и делал первичными. В качестве устройства для загрузчика выбираю саму флешку (именно флешку, а не раздел на ней). На родном ПК, где появился загрузчик после первой установки (либо не то указал, либо не туда поставился ибо не было efi) система работает отлично, но на любом другом, при загрузке с флешки (usb hdd:"имя флешки"), она просто пропускается и грузиться windows (стоит на самом ПК). Собственно это и проблема

Что пробовал:

Менял порядок запуска в bios

Выключал быструю загрузку

Проверял наличие включённого usb flash boot в bios

Менял с uefi на legacy support

Устанавливал систему в автоматическом режиме

Отключал security boot

Ну и ещё рандомные действия, которые ничему не привели.

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете)

Comment: На разделе efi файл `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` существует?

Comment: Трудно гадать на расстоянии. И чтобы много не гадать и писать, вот ссылка на 100% рабочую процедуру: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BcVJT8eLv8. Сравните с ней, что у вас не так.

Comment: @void прозвучит странно, но по-прежнему не работает

Comment: @andreymal я переустанавливал по комментарию void и нет, нету. Проверял через установочный образ ubuntu, почему-то занят 1мб (498 из 499), но при просмотре раздел полностью пустой.

Comment: @Slava раздел efi не может быть полностью пустым, потому что тогда система вообще не грузилась бы. Или вы что-то путаете, или загрузчик всё-таки случайно установился на другой диск

Comment: @andreymal я это понимаю, и она собственно и не грузится. Я это проверял, загрузившись с другой флешки, на который установлен рабочий образ системы, который используют для установки нормальной, полноценной.

Нужная система сама не грузится (при загрузке с флешки), но при использовании загрузчика, который стоит на пк - вполне. на других пк такого загрузчика нет, он должен быть на флешке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, загрузчик ставился на диск, а не на флешку (хотя выбирал правильно). Поставил загрузчик вручную и подправил fstab, что бы на других ПК работало

Comment: Ну так об этом и было в ролике, что я скинул в комментарии к вопросу.